# What is the exact security benefit of disconnected environments?

Tags: network-access-control

In large organizations, I often see sysadmins mirroring all the stuff they need from the internet locally (container images, rpm and deb packages) for local consumption, with the burden of keeping the local repositories  up to date on your own.
I don't see what is the benefit of that approach compared to having an forward proxy, configured to only allow outgoing traffic to a list of specific trusted URLs.

I know that this disconnected setup is mandatory in some entities, but I find difficult to understand the exact benefit.

Comment: Some servers can't connect to the internet and are only available from the internal network. That would be one reason for mirroring the repositories.

Comment: the less exposure something has to attacks, the more secure something is.

Comment: **TUF** was designed because the possibility of malicious software updates can be a concern (see the rationale considerations: https://theupdateframework.io/security/).

Answer (score 1):

There are some systems which perform extremely valuable operations, often of a cryptographic nature, where the compromise of the system would have catastrophic implications.  One of these is the system used for the DNSSEC keys for the root zone.  Other organizations may have highly trusted root keys such as CA authority root keys, where compromise could be fatal or at least highly damaging to the business.  Other examples include machines that perform lottery drawings, where there is obviously a huge financial incentive to compromise the machine.

There are also situations where people have systems that run essential hardware (e.g., SCADA systems) that is known to have security problems, but cannot be upgraded because no newer version of the software is available (say, because the manufacturer no longer supports it or has gone out of business).  It is especially common in such environments that simple operations such as port scanning can affect the operation of these systems negatively in a safety-relevant way.  For example, I've heard about a case where running nmap might cause the system running gas turbines at a power plant to explode.

In these environments, removing the machine from direct access to the Internet or even disconnecting it entirely from the network can significantly improve the security posture.  Obviously, if it is possible, one should apply security upgrades on a regular basis and one should strongly prefer systems and software that are receiving regular updates, but for highly sensitive systems, an additional layer of defense by preventing Internet access altogether can be valuable.  It is, after all, substantially more difficult to compromise a machine remotely when it is not accessible remotely.

Comment: " It is, after all, substantially more difficult to compromise a machine remotely when it is not accessible remotely. " How do you compromise a machine  remotely when that machine sole acccess to the external world is a forwarding proxy ?

Comment: You could try to replace one of the resources it requests with something malicious.  If it executes code (e.g., packages) it receives from its proxy, then that would allow compromised.